# Sort string in alphabetical order in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label, a text field and a button. The user introduces a sequence of letters in the text field, e.g. "gcea", presses the button, and the label text becomes "aceg".

What i have so far in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *random;
- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender;

@end
```

What i have so far in .m

```
- (IBAction)ok:(id)sender {


    NSString *order = self.random.text;
    NSInteger compare = order.length;
    NSString *corect = @"abc";

    // will insert all letters when it will actually work:)


    BOOL count = YES;

    for  (int i=0;i<compare;i++)

    {
        if([corect characterAtIndex:i] == [order characterAtIndex:i])

        {
            //do stuff?;


        }

    }


    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", count];



}
@end
```

So what should I do next from here? My thought process is that I compare my "correct" string to what the user put in char by char and print the result in another string. But I have no idea how to actually write this, so can anyone please give me some pointers?

Also please don't use any predefined methods, I want to understand bools & for loops better first.

I'm brand new to programming.

Comment: You seem to have skipped diving into the deep end, instead you've jumped over the side of a cruise ship and you're asking someone to toss you a life preserver -- which might help you stay afloat until you die of starvation or exposure!

Comment: If you have literally zero experience in programming, then you're not gonna write a sort yourself.

Comment: If you don't want to use built-in methods for comparison, look into basic sorting algorithms (& common coding interview problems). Do you want to match a target string, or alphabetize the input? Those are different. Your idea of comparing (use < or >, not ==) & storing sorted one is a start. This also gets tricky w/different alphabets (w/umlauts, accents, etc), which is why people use the built-in localized comparison methods. Finally, look into code structure. Do you really want to lock that work into a button response? Or maybe encapsulate it as its own method so you can reuse it elsewhere?

Comment: You need to know what an NSArray is, and where it's documentation is located.

Comment: Thanks for the response mc01, i will try to look into it that way. I just want to alphabetize the input & lock that work into a button response(will try the advance stuff after i figure this out)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other posters that your question was a duplicate of the linked post.

Several things:

First: Sorting is actually a very complex subject. I suggest you read the wiki article on sorting. Naive sorting algorithms like bubble sort are easy to write, but VERY inefficient. Their time to sort tends to go up with the square of the number of elements being sorted, which is bad news for sorting longer lists. Still, learning a naive sorting algorithm is a worthwhile exercise.

Second: NSString, and it's mutable subclass, NSMutableString, don't really lend themselves to manipulating a string character by character.

The suggestion of creating an array of single-character strings isn't bad as a learning exercise, or perhaps even sorting a C string.

You might want to start with a simpler problem like sorting a C array of numbers. Here is some sample code to do that:

```
//Create an array of mixed-up integers
int array[] = {73, 12, 135, 18, 200, 1, 416};


//an outer loop for indexing into the array starting at the first element and going to 
//the next-to-last item.
for (int outer = 0; outer < sizeof(array)-1; outer++)
{ 

  //An inner loop that starts one past the current outer loop, 
  //and goes to the end of the array
  for (int inner = outer+1; inner< sizeof(array); inner++);
  {
    //If the items at the outer and inner loop indexes are out of order, swap them
    if (array[outer] > array[inner])
    {
      int temp = array[outer];
      array[outer] = array[inner];
      array[inner] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is a bad sort algorithm. For an array of n elements, it always does n^2 comparisons. However, it's fairly easy to understand what it does.

In standard computer science terminology, this is known as O(n squared) performance, or just n squared performance, which is bad news.

You could adapt the code above to sort characters in an NSString, but it would be kind of painful. As somebody else suggested, you'd have to break your string into a mutable array of NSNumbers that hold the value of each character in the string, then use code like the above to sort the array of numbers.

Test that sort algorithm on a string of 100 characters. It will seem fast. Then give it a string of 10,000 characters. It will take quite a while. That's because it will have to do 10,000 x 10,000, or 100 million comparisons.

Next look up a sort like quicksort or shell sort. Those are more work to figure out and implement, but much, much more efficient. If I remember correctly both of those sort algorithms typically have n * log(n) performance, which is MUCH better.